# Stop scrolling over edge of screen on iOS web apps?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

Working on an iOS web app. The user can scroll the content of the page up and down. However, is there a way to stop the screen from being dragged so far that the grey background becomes visible? This is replicable by opening any webpage in mobile safari and pulling the page down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript library like pastrykit, or iScroll, to handle the scrolling instead of the default, similarly to how the mobile gmail webpage works, or the iPhone User Guide.

Comment: Yeah, I have used those before. But for this, I don't need anything like that I'm not trying to simulate fixed positioning. I think if I can figure out how to detect when the grey background is visible, I can stop touchmove with preventDefault(). Gotta figure out how to do the detection though.

Comment: Well, you would make the entire webpage in a div controlled by one of the above. That would take over scrolling, and then the user could not scroll enough to make the grey background visible.